# Where do I get a Magical Gem?

Tags: happy-street

I am trying to build a plane to take me to the mountains. Problem is, I now need a magical gem to complete one of Billy's quests.

I have never seen this gem anywhere.

Where do I get it? Do I have to ask a friend for it, and hope they have one? Or is it something I can craft somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you get the Magical Gem as a quest reward - a few hours or so after Billy asks you for the Magical Gem for his plane, Pepin will tell you about a family heirloom that he wants to give to you in exchange for a lotus flower. Once you craft the lotus flower for Pepin, he will give you the Magical Gem that Billy needs.

Comment: I'm not sure time really has to pass.  In my case, it was basically instant after Billy gave the other quest.

Answer (score 3):

Pepin will give you it after Billy gives you the quest and you give him a black lotus created by crafting three gold tulips, three blue tulips, and three red tulips.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to give Pepin the Lotus flower once you complete the quest he will give you the magical gem.

Answer (score 0):

Pepin will give you a magic gem after the family herloom quest.